# Using jq how do I search against an array of strings?

Tags: jq

The following gives me the logins of authors that have contributed to stedolan's jq repo:

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq '.[].author.login'
```

With the following result:

```
"nicowilliams"
"dtolnay"
"nicowilliams"
"nicowilliams"
"stedolan"
```

How do I search for commits from specific authors?  For example, if I only want to return commits from "dtolnay" and "stedolan"?

I can for example get commit messages from just 'stedolan'; however, I'd like to do something like `select(.author.login in("stedolan", "dtolnay"))`

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=20' | jq '.[] | select(.author.login == "stedolan") | .commit.message'
```

Comment: Thanks @JeffMercado, that works perfectly: `curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=50' | jq --argjson whitelist '["stedolan", "dtolnay"]' '.[] | select(.author.login == $whitelist[]) | {author: .author.login, message: .commit.message}'`

Comment: @JeffMercado, that works; however, inverting with ` | not` doesn't... Any suggestions? `curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=50' | jq --argjson whitelist '["stedolan", "dtolnay"]' '.[] | select(.author.login == $whitelist[] | not) | {author: .author.login, message: .commit.message}'`